# Multiline string concatenation

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, formatting

## Problem Description

Printing the result of adding two numpy arrays together is very ugly.

Here we will use these numpy arrays as an example:

```py
import numpy as np
arr_2d = np.array([[3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 1]])
arr_1d = np.array([3,4,5])
```

Here are a few of the ugly ways to print the formula `arr_2d + arr_1d` that are low-effort and ugly:

1. Format strings

```py
>>> print(f"{arr_1d}\n+\n{arr_2d}\n=\n{arr_1d + arr_2d}")
[3 4 5]
+
[[3 3 3]
 [3 3 1]
 [2 3 1]]
=
[[6 7 8]
 [6 7 6]
 [5 7 6]]
```

method 2 - printing as a list

```py
>>> print([arr_1d,'+',arr_2d,'=',(arr_1d + arr_2d)])
[array([3, 4, 5]), '+', array([[3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 1]]), '=', array([[6, 7, 8],
       [6, 7, 6],
       [5, 7, 6]])]
```

### Solution

To solve this problem I used the following code:

```py
def multiline_concat (*args):
    """
    Concatenates arguments into a single str. 
    Supports multiline strs and arguments that become multiline strs when cast to str
    """
    str_args = []
    for arg_index, arg in enumerate(args):
        try:
            str_args.append(str(arg))
        except TypeError as e:
            raise TypeError(f"""ERROR: parameter passed to multiline_concat at index
                                {arg_index} of type {type(arg)} cannot be converted to a str""")
    output_rows = []
    row_len = 0
    for col in str_args: # each value in *args is a column
        col_lines = col.split('\n')
        col_width = 0
        for row_index, cell in enumerate(col_lines):
            if len(output_rows) <= row_index: # Row doesn't exist yet so we add it.
                output_rows.append("")
            col_width = max(len(cell), col_width)
            # padding the row so cells in this column start at the same index, then appending the cell
            output_rows[row_index] = output_rows[row_index].ljust(row_len) + cell
        row_len += col_width
    return '\n'.join(output_rows)
```

we can now concatenate multi-line strings like this:

```py
>>> print(multiline_concat(arr_1d, '+', arr_2d, '=',(arr_1d + arr_2d)))
[3 4 5] + [[3 3 3]  = [[6 7 8]
           [3 3 1]     [6 7 6]
           [2 3 1]]    [5 7 6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A while ago I created the same function.
I was creating a number of formatting functions, and found working against `str` or `Any` to introduce a significant amount of boiler plate.
As such I'd recommend splitting the function into two:

1. A core function interacting with `Iterable[str]`, and
2. A helper function which interacts with `Any` and returns a `str`.

---

Looking at the helper code:

1. Not a fan of whitespace after function names `def multiline_concat (*args)`.
2. Not a fan of the names you're using around `arg` and would change to `column`.
3. You don't need `as e`.
4. The multiline string is going to keep a ton of whitespace in the error message, you shouldn't use a multiline here. Instead use two normal strings with implicit concatenation.
5. I would introduce a `sep` variable to allow specifying a custom separator.

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator
from typing import Any


def _multiline_concat(
    *columns: Iterable[str],
    sep: str = " ",
) -> Iterator[str]:
    output_rows = []
    row_len = 0
    for col_lines in columns: # each value in *args is a column
        col_width = 0
        for row_index, cell in enumerate(col_lines):
            if len(output_rows) <= row_index: # Row doesn't exist yet so we add it.
                output_rows.append("")
            col_width = max(len(cell), col_width)
            # padding the row so cells in this column start at the same index, then appending the cell
            output_rows[row_index] = output_rows[row_index].ljust(row_len) + cell
        row_len += col_width
    yield from output_rows


def multiline_concat(
    *columns: Any,
    sep: str = " ",
) -> str:
    """
    Concatenates arguments into a single str. 
    Supports multiline strs and arguments that become multiline strs when cast to str
    """
    columns_: list[list[str]] = []
    for column in columns:
        try:
            columns_.append(str(column).splitlines())
        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError(
                f"ERROR: parameter passed to multiline_concat at index"
                f" {len(columns_)} of type {type(column)} cannot be converted to a str"
            )
    return "\n".join(_multiline_concat(*columns_, sep=sep))
```

---

Looking at the core function `_multiline_concat`:

1. Once you have `col_lines` you can `col_width` by getting the max size:

   ```
   col_width = max(len(item) for item in col_lines)
   ```
2. The approach is clever and is simple if you are not aware of [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

   With `zip_longest` you can iterate through all the columns getting the row each time. Simplifying the code, as `output_rows` and `row_len` are likely a little trick to work around.

   With `zip` we merge the row with the pre-computed widths, so we can `item.ljust(width)` each value.

```py
import itertools


def _multiline_concat(
    *columns: Iterable[str],
    sep: str = " ",
) -> Iterator[str]:
    columns_ = [list(c) for c in columns]
    columns_width = [
        max(len(item) for item in column)
        for column in columns_
    ]
    for row in itertools.zip_longest(*columns_, fillvalue=""):
        yield sep.join(
            item.ljust(width)
            for item, width in zip(row, columns_width)
        )
```